# Export issue in grid collection when apply groupby in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting only 1000 rows in csv and excel when i am applying group by query in my collection
and also get wrong number of records in grid pager.

```
$collections->getSelect()->group('main_table.name');
```

If i am comment this line all works fine.

Let me know if you need more info.